# Issue with MySQL connection inside class

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I have a MySQL class that I use to connect to MySQL. But after doing the upgrade of PHP to 5.4.16, it doesn't work any more. Can anyone help with it? 

Below is the code that I use. Whenever I try to connect it gets into the error part.

```
final class MySQL {
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
            if (!$this->connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
            exit('Error: Could not make a database connection using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to get more useful information if you look in `mysql_error`. But you should really look at upgrading to `mysqli_` or `PDO`, as the `mysql_` library is deprecated, and indeed removed from PHP 7

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and removed in the latest version of PHP. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/934739.

Comment: It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you evaluated [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before going down this path?

Comment: I don't think its based on mysql_ deprecated.When I use the mysql_connect outside of class, it works. But when using it inside the above class, it shows error. The error that I receive is "Can't connect to MySQL server on '[mysql server]' (13)"

Comment: OK. I narrowed it a bit more. When I run the script on linux shell like ">php script.php" it is able to connect. But when executing the same on browser it throws the above error of not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : Did the following on command prompt and 

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

More details here : 
https://maanasroyy.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/php-cant-connect-to-mysql-with-error-13-but-command-line-can/